# Devise not inherting Twitter Bootstrap Styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I'm learning Rails and was trying out the Devise gem. I have the bootstrap-sass gem installed and have imported the bootstrap css and javascript files successfully. Bootstrap works fine with forms and buttons for resources that I create.

However, the forms and buttons generated by Devise don't inherit the Bootstrap styling and they retain their plain looks. In many tutorials I've read/watched, the Bootstrap style is automatically applied to Devise views. Wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm using Rails 3.2, Bootstrap 3 and Devise 3.2.2. Thanks in advance!
Here's the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/AImtK.png

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please edit your question to include the code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following an outdated tutorial video. From what I have learned so far, Devise have to be stylized for Bootstrap just like we do other forms.